# How get list of days in a week that exist in some date range (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

Hello I need to define existing days in some date range.
I don't wont to make loop from start to end dates and use like here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getday.asp
Is it possible to calculate it some how ?

Comment: *I don't want to make loop from start to end dates.* Do you actually want to build a list without using a loop? This will probably be more hassle than it's worth (and alternate constructs like recursion arguably count as looping).

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you want? What do you mean _define existing days in some date range_?

Comment: for example I have 01-01-2012 to 20-01-2012 date range. and I need define that all days in a week are included. In case 01-01-2012 to 02-01-2012 just Tuesday and Wednesday is selected. It doesn't matter that date range is selected.

Comment: Looping the dates will be an easy way of doing this.  
As @FrédéricHamidi mentioned it will be very hassle. If you need here is an example with looping
 http://jsfiddle.net/rajaasthana/JBWuW/

Comment: Yes but what if user select  01-01-2012 to  01-01-3000 it could be a little big loop :) If think with new Date(dTo - dFrom).getTime() >= 518400000 I will cut it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function getDays(earlierDate, laterDate) {
  var dayNames = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
  var elapsedDays = (laterDate - earlierDate) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
  if (elapsedDays < 7) {
    var dayArray = [];
    for (i = 0; i <= elapsedDays; i++) {
        dayArray.push(dayNames[(earlierDate.getDay()+i) % 7]);
    }
    return dayArray;
  }
  return dayNames;
}
```

And testing in the js console:

```
> getDays(new Date("03-01-2012"), new Date("03-01-2012"));
["Thursday"]
> getDays(new Date("03-01-2012"), new Date("03-05-2012"));
["Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday"]
> getDays(new Date("03-01-2012"), new Date("03-05-2013"));
["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var sevenDaysInMS = 604800000;
    if (new Date(dTo - dFrom).getTime() >= sevenDaysInMS) {
        $('.day_hid').attr(attrUnaviableDay, "true");
    } else {
        var dt = dFrom;
        do {
            var day = dt.getDay();
            ActivateDaySelector(day);
            dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
        } while (dt <= dTo);
    }
```

I think it is ok. What do you think ?